# Android GridView Selected Item Background color change while pressing

Tags: android, gridview, background, imageview, background-color

I have the imageview using gridview in my android application.so while pressing the image in gridview,the background color want to change.if i return ,it will come to normal background color.How to do this?can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Here my code

```
public class CustomGridViewExample extends Activity {

    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.android_2,
            R.drawable.android_2,
            R.drawable.android_2,
            R.drawable.android_2,
            R.drawable.android_2,
            R.drawable.android_2,
            R.drawable.android_2,
            R.drawable.android_2,
            R.drawable.android_2,
            R.drawable.android_2,


            };


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this));
        gridview.setNumColumns(4);
    }

  public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context mContext;

        public MyAdapter(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return mThumbIds[arg0];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return arg0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 

            View grid;

            if(convertView==null){
                grid = new View(mContext);
                LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
                grid=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mygrid_layout, parent, false);
            }else{
                grid = (View)convertView;
            }

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.image);
            imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

            return grid;
        }

    }
```

And related XML file is below :

```
<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/gridview" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:numColumns="auto_fit" 
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" 
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp" 
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:scrollbars="none" />

mygrid_layout.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/customshape_header"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/image" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

in your Drawable folder create grid_selector.xml.
Then edit the following::`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/green" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/blue" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/white"/>

</selector>`
```

Then in ur mygrid_layout.xml file set this file as background in  relative layout ..

Answer (score 0):

in your mygrid_layout.xml for relative layout use selector with ur required color as background .

Comment: which xml shall i use selector with background ?main.xml or mygrid_layout.xml